# How can I tell whether Ubuntu One file sync is working, and what progress it is making?

Tags: ubuntu-one

It is not clear how the file sync aspect of Ubuntu One is started, nor
whether it is running at any given point in time, nor what the
progress is being made during sync.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the process in charge of keeping a user's file synced with
the user's cloud storage on Ubuntu One is called the "Ubuntu One
SyncDaemon". It lives in
`/usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon`, and is included in a
default Ubuntu Desktop installation. In this default install a
lightweight check is made as to whether you are signed up to Ubuntu
One, and if so the syncdaemon is started automatically for you, 30
seconds after login. The syncdaemon then checks your files for local
changes, and then connects to the server; after the initial
synchronization, everything should "just work".

> A few bugs can get in the way of things "just working"; most notable
>   right now are [LP:651237](http://launchpad.net/bugs/651237) (which has been fixed, and we're working on
>   getting it out to everybody affected) and [LP:683116](http://launchpad.net/bugs/683116) (which is in
>   progress and should be fixed before 10.04.2).

There are several ways you can confirm that it is working for you. The
easiest is probably to open `ubuntuone-preferences`, which you can
find under System > Preferences > Ubuntu One:

[ubuntuone-preferences http://ubuntuone.com/p/ScT/](http://ubuntuone.com/p/ScT/)

Note the "Synchronization complete" label; this can change to
"Synchronization in progress..." or "Disconnected", as
appropriate. Furthermore the device with the bandwidth limits controls
and the Connect/Disconnect/Restart buttons is the local computer.

Some people want more information than "working/not working"; Roman
Yepishev developed a very nice indicator for the syncdaemon, which
[you can read about on his blog](http://blog.rtg.in.ua/2010/10/have-you-seen-my-weather-applet.html) and install via the ppa:
[`ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras`](https://launchpad.net/~rye/+archive/ubuntuone-extras). It looks like this:

[roman's indicator http://ubuntuone.com/p/J4U/](http://ubuntuone.com/p/J4U/)

You can get a little more detail by opening a terminal and typing
`u1sdtool --status`. Note that is `u-one-ess-dee` (for Ubuntu One Sync
Daemon), not `u-ell-ess-dee`. One piece of valuable information you
can get from `u1sdtool` is the progress of individual transfers, as
you can see:

[u1sdtool http://ubuntuone.com/p/Scd/](http://ubuntuone.com/p/Scd/)

Another way is by installing
[magicicada](http://packages.ubuntu.com/magicicada) [image: Install magicicada]

If you're in 10.04 LTS, you can grab it off [`ppa:chicharreros/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~chicharreros/+archive/ppa).
`magicicada` connects you straight into the firehose of information
put out by the `syncdaemon`, so beware:

[magicicada http://ubuntuone.com/p/Scc/](http://ubuntuone.com/p/Scc/)

### the future

In the [brainstorm that inspired this Q/A](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25417/), [solution #1](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25417/#solution-title-34482) looks very nice, but is
probably beyond what we can build right now (but we'd take
patches!). A variation of this might be possible by abusing the
emblems a little; it's currently being looked into.

[Solution #2](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25417/#solution-title-34483) has a problem that as far as I can tell makes it
unimplementable: progress of the file sync as a whole is very hard to
present to the user in a meaningful way, because the "whole" can and
will change during the synchronization process.

[Solution #5](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25417/#solution-title-34733) is what is coming in 11.04: we're integrating syncdaemon
with the zeitgeist engine, and will be using zeitgeist to help us
aggregate the events when necessary and present the user with useful
status information (rather than the deluge that was the applet). The
majority of this work still needs to be done, so unfortunately there
is nothing to show.

If Ubuntu gained a [unified way of reporting progress](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/18502/)),
we'd work to interface with that; this would presumably give us
[notifications for large up/downloads](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24057/) as well

Comment: woot, Chipaca your answer is wonderful =)

Comment: All your images are dead now that Ubuntu One is gone.

Answer (score 19):

You can do it by CLI or install a indicator:

### CLI

**To check the status of ubuntuone (connected, etc) do:**

```
u1sdtool -s
```

It will print something like:

```
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
    connection: With User With Network
    description: processing queues
    is_connected: True
    is_error: False
    is_online: True
    queues: IDLE
```

**To check the current transfers (upload/download) do:**

```
u1sdtool --current-transfers
```

It will print something like:

```
Current uploads:
  path: /home/marcos/Ubuntu One/Imagens/Flames/legendary-trap (cópia).jpg
    deflated size: 49724
    bytes written: 0
Current downloads: 0
```

### GUI

Install the ubuntuone-indicator indicator that will provide some info on the tray area.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-indicator
```

Answer (score 3):

If the status description is "processing queues" and the queues message is "WORKING_ON_BOTH", the `--current-transfer` option will not be very useful in determing activity. In this case, I've found the following command, which gets a count of files' metadata being processed, to help in determining activity:

```
u1sdtool --waiting-meta | wc -l
```

Once transfers begin, you will get some info from the `--current-transfer` option. However, it won't give you much of a status report. Another command,  which gets a count of files waiting to sync, can be useful in determining progress:

```
u1sdtool --waiting-content | wc -l
```

In Ubuntu 11.04 and newer these two commands have been combined:

```
u1sdtool --waiting | wc -l
```