# Computer shows up twice, connection unknown

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, couchdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicated entries in Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19792/duplicated-entries-in-ubuntu-one)
>   [why does my UbuntuOne sync only upload folders and zero content?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20616/why-does-my-ubuntuone-sync-only-upload-folders-and-zero-content)
>   [How can I tell whether Ubuntu One file sync is working, and what progress it is making?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16592/how-can-i-tell-whether-ubuntu-one-file-sync-is-working-and-what-progress-it-is-m)

Added two computers to Ubuntu One. One machine is windows. The windows version seems to work fine, and I started syncing a folder by placing it into the Ubuntu One folder. All files and folders are visible when I go to my account online.

On Ubuntu machine. I selected to sync the Download folder. Shortly thereafter, I realized that one folder exceeded my storage max. I tried to un-sync the folder, but Ubuntu One and the Stop Syncing This Folder were not visible in the menu.

Per Ubuntu instructions, I removed my Ubuntu computer from the list of syncing computers.

Per Ubuntu instructions, I re-added the Ubuntu computer. However, I find that two computers by the same name are added on both the desktop app and on the web. Plus, I the connection is "unknown."

I have removed and re-added the computer several times with the same results. In all cases, I remove the computers using the Ubuntu One desktop app, then removing them from my account on the web, removing the Ubuntu One password, and restart the Ubuntu One app.

Problem remains.

Thanks in advance for any replies and help.

Comment: I think this is answered by [Duplicated entries in Ubuntu One](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19792/duplicated-entries-in-ubuntu-one) and [why does my UbuntuOne sync only upload folders and zero content?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20616/why-does-my-ubuntuone-sync-only-upload-folders-and-zero-content). Please also consider [How can I tell whether Ubuntu One file sync is working, and what progress it is making?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16592/).