# Duplicated entries in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I recently started using Ubuntu One.  Somehow, when I look at Ubuntu One Preferences->Devices, one of my laptop computers is listed twice.  When I visit my Ubuntu One account via web, "Computers on your account" also lists that particular laptop twice.
I am wondering why this happens, and whether I can remove one of them.
Thank you very much for your help!
BVP

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove the bottom one. You can get multiple entries for a computer when you authorize a machine multiple times. As the machine will only keep the latest tokens it got from the server, you can safely remove the other, older ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple device entries for Ubuntu One you can use the following steps to determine which devices to keep and which to delete. Be aware that it is not uncommon to have two entries. One for Ubuntu One and one for Tomboy.

1. Open Password and Encryption Keys (seahorse).
2. Navigate to the 'Passwords' tab and click to expand the Passwords folder.
3. Right-click on the Ubuntu One Token and select 'Properties'.
4. Select the 'Key' tab.
5. Click the triangle to reveal the password and check the 'show password' box.
6. Find the random letter sequence that appears after 'token=' and write it down or paste it into a text document.
7. From the terminal run the command gconf-editor.
8. In the left panel navigate through the folder tree to apps --> tomboy --> sync and click on tomboyweb.
9. In the right panel you will see a value called 'oauth_token' with another random letter sequence next to it. Write this letter sequence down or copy it to the same file as in Step 6.
10. Open your browser and go to https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/ .
11. Compare the letter sequences from steps 6 & 9 with the letter sequences found next to the devices listed on the web site. The devices 'who's letter sequence matches are the ones you wish to keep.