# Why do two pc's show up on my account when I  only own one?

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicated entries in Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19792/duplicated-entries-in-ubuntu-one)

When I look at my account, it shows that two computers are connected to my account. I only have the one that I am using? Why would two show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the unneeded PC from the list. The reason for 1 PC showing as two are multiple - especially with the given level of information. Maybe you had to re-authenticate your PC with a different name? Or it's simply a bug which I recommend you to [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug) on Launchpad.