# FIles not synced

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My folders have been synced but I don't see any files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35366/my-folders-have-been-synced-but-i-dont-see-any-files)

I've signed up for the mobile plan. I've started with the free 2gb space. I've copied some mp3 files and directorioes into "Ubuntu One" directory.
After create some of the directories I copied (only directories), the agent simply stopped the sync. After 40 minutos of nothing, I've restarted it, and it resumed the directory creation. No files yet. 
Disconnect and connect again, and it started to sync files. I leave it overnight, and it upload only 300mb before stop syncing again. I have to disconnect/connect again.
I have Ubuntu 10.10 and a fast connection (never had this problem with dropbox).

I think I won't go on after the trial month. I cannot even check what file is being uploaded, I have to navigate the slow web interface to figure it out, peeking directory thru directory. The config window doesn't even update the space used until I restart it. It's very annoying.

Do you have some pointer for me to improve the experience? So far is simply awful.
Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

There is a known performance issue when syncing many files (500 or more). This will improve as we make a change on the server side in the next couple weeks. We've also made many improvements on the client side in Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) which we're going to try to make available to other versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. It works better now. Also I've installed third party ubuntuone-indicator and it becoming very usable now. I think I'll stay with mobile after the trial, and will buy maybe a 20gb pack, as bottomline is a good product and I'd like to help canonical. Thanks!