# How do I get Ubuntu Music to sync my existing collection?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, mp3

I signed up for the free, 30-day trial of Ubuntu Mobile last night. Really in hopes that I could aggregate my music collection and make it available to my mobile devices. I shared my 'Music' folder on my laptop (Ubuntu 11.4). It synced with the server, but it only uploaded the file structure and some random text files, images. ie, everything BUT the music.

So, how do I get my existing music onto the server so that I can access it on my android phone? Am I missing a tutorial somewhere?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what version of Ubuntu you're on and on what your connectivity is like, uploading your entire collection can take a significant amount of time. Don't despair, as it most likely [will be making progress](https://askubuntu.com/q/16592/711); if it doesn't, it's a [bug I'd need you to report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug?field.title=syncdaemon%20making%20no%20progress).

Comment: Should it take more than 7 hours to do 3 albums? I unsynced the music folder and retested with a subset. They're still not on the server. my internet connection should be more than fast enough to transfer this.