# Nothing seems to be syncing with Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

So earlier tonight I set up Ubuntu One on a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10. In my "Ubuntu One" directory, I created symbolic links to /Documents /Pictures and /Music. Right now, there is VERY little in those directories but what IS there isn't syncing at all.

When I go to the Ubuntu One web interface, it tells me I'm using 0.00% of my storage space. When I try to view the files in the web interface, I am told 'Something has gone wrong' and I don't see anything.

Can anyone help? Even my Tomboy notes aren't syncing!  And yes, I am connected and the software says 'Synchronisation Complete'

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: Welcome to AU! Try these steps here and then edit your question with progress: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16592/how-can-i-tell-whether-ubuntu-one-file-sync-is-working-and-what-progress-it-is-m

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One [does not sync symlinks at all](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/does-ubuntu-one-support-symlinks-or-hard-links/). The way to sync arbitrary folders is by going to the folder in nautilus and selecting `Synchronize this folder` from either the ribbon if it's visible,

[image: “synchronize this folder” in the nautilus ribbon]

or from the `File › Ubuntu One` menu if it's not,

[image: “Synchronize this folder” in the nautilus “File” menu]

or from the `Ubuntu One` submenu of the right-click menu in the parent directory,

[image]

or, from the command line, using `u1sdtool --create-folder /path/to/folder`.