# How can I see what files Ubuntu One has synced?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell whether Ubuntu One file sync is working, and what progress it is making?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16592/how-can-i-tell-whether-ubuntu-one-file-sync-is-working-and-what-progress-it-is)

During sync Ubuntu One displays a notification saying something like "'filename.xxx' and 59 other files are being uploaded to your personal cloud." How can I check what those other (59) files are? None of the log files in .cache/ubuntuone/log seem to log this information **in a user friendly way**.

I know that I could use u1sdtool to see what is being synced in real-time. But, however, after the sync has taken place is there no way of knowing what happened?

Comment: Actually, .cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon.log does log sync events, however, it is hard read, essentially impossible do discern what 59 files was synced and how.

Comment: As I was wrong about the log file, I updated the original post with the bold text.

Comment: I read your excellent answer in the other post before I asked this question, however, I don't think you covered how to read log files, how to find out what files have been uploaded, downloaded, etc.

Comment: yup,that's why i answered below

Answer (score 4):

Possibly the most user friendly place where this is (somewhat) exposed is [gnome-activity-journal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-activity-journal) [image: Install gnome-activity-journal]. You'll have to dig around quite a bit, but at least at the file level they are there (folders, however, seem to be missing). For example, yesterday I created a new synchronized folder with a bunch of images in it, and the images appear in `gnome-activity-journal` like so:

[image: gnome-activity-journal]

One rather developer friendly way of figuring out what has been synced is using the REST API to query the server. Using `u1oauthrequest` (which you can find in the `ubuntuone-couch` package—don't worry, it does not depend on couchdb), and the [API documentation that you can read on our developers website](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud), you can quickly drill in to the synced content.

The syncdaemon log does contain the information of what has synced (depending on your logging level, which is configurable), but as you found you'd have to write something to extract the information you're looking for. However, syncdaemon does send events to zeitgeist, so you could query it with something like the following:

```
from zeitgeist import client, datamodel
import gobject

def on_ev_recv(evs):
    for ev in evs:
        print ev.get_interpretation().encode('utf-8'),
        print ev.get_subjects()[0].get_origin().encode('utf-8')

mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
client = client.ZeitgeistClient()

client.find_events_for_template(
    datamodel.Event.new_for_values(actor='dbus://com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.service'),
    on_ev_recv,
    result_type=datamodel.ResultType.MostRecentEvents,
    num_events=1000)

mainloop.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not a developer, so this is not an option for me.

Comment: added a bit about `gnome-activity-journal`